# Has my fast been broken?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, masturbation

Assalamualaikum, I masturbated and stopped before ejaculating but i ended up ejaculating due to the stimulus. Does that break my fast?

I know it is a sinful act especially at the month of Ramadan. I am trying to stop this act inshallah in the month of Ramadan.

Please respond as soon as possible

Comment: Questions like this appear each year and they already are answered on the site. Check the site prior to asking question duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Asalaamu'alaikum. I am not a scholar myself but it appears your fast has broken if you have ejaculated. I understand that it is indeed a sinful act but the result of this is because your nafs is strongly held onto this habit. Please do your best to stay away from this habit during this Ramadan and do your best to continue keeping away from this habit even after Ramadan as there are no benefits to you from this.

You will lose your confidence, willpower and you will experience anxiety all for the sake of a few moments pleasure. It is truly not worth it but I understand your struggle, May Allah SWT make this easy for you.

You will have to make your fast up of today.

For your reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YvXom5yNZG4

May Allah strengthen you and give you the ability to overcome this habit.